# Need to Detect a Click inside Complex Component and return the Component ID

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am using react for development and for performance reason i want o capture the click a topmost parent level.

```
const clickHandler = (e) => {
  console.log("clickHandler", e.target) --> give me the child element in which the click occurred
}
```

so even if the nested child i should be able to get the ID. And there are going be 1000's card and the childen structure is also complex

```
<div onClick={clickHandler}>

<div class="card" id="12345">
   <div class="x1">
   <div class="x2">
      <div class="">
         <span class="">
         <ul class="">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="card" id="67890">
   <div class="x1">
   <div class="x2">
      <div class="">
         <span class="">
         <ul class="">
   </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think no way : ))
Give the handler to child card by any way (props, context ...) or calculate by mouse position : ))

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the `id` of the element with the `card` class when you click anywhere inside it.

You can use `.closest` to find the relevant parent you want.

Keep in mind that this is not react related, and it also seems like an anti pattern going at it this way.

```
const clickHandler = (e) => {
  const relatedCard = e.target.closest(".card");
  if (relatedCard) {
    console.log("clickHandler", relatedCard.id);
  } else {
    console.log("click happened outside of a .card element");
  }
};
```

---

A more react related solution would be to put the click handler on that element instead of the container div and use the id directly.

```
<div>

<div class="card" id="12345" onClick={() => clickHandler('12345')}>
   <div class="x1">
   <div class="x2">
      <div class="">
         <span class="">
         <ul class="">
   </div>
</div>

<div class="card" id="67890" onClick={() => clickHandler('67890')}>
   <div class="x1">
   <div class="x2">
      <div class="">
         <span class="">
         <ul class="">
   </div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

After some reading i found this article ,

https://dev.to/thawsitt/should-i-use-event-delegation-in-react-nl0

in which Dan Abhromov state that, there is no advantage of doing this in react. As React using Synthetic events and event is already being captured in the root element.